# Using nested json_arrayagg with two table which have many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, query, json

Consider following two tables in mysql database

```
role(role_id);
task(task_id);
```

and a pivot table

```
role(role_id,task_id)
```

I can extract a single role in JSON format using the following query

```
select json_object
           (
               'id', r.role_uuid,
               'tasks', (select json_arrayagg(
                                       json_object(
                                               'id', t.task_id
                                           ))
                        from role r
                                 inner join role_task rt on r.role_id = rt.role_id
                                 inner join task t on rt.task_id = t.task_id
                        where r.role_id = @role_1)
           )
from role r
where r.role_id = @role_1;
```

However, I can't figure out how to do it when where condition returns more than one role.

For example, if I modify the where condition to following

```
where r.role_id =@role_1 or r.role_id=@role_2;
```

Comment: Provide an example: sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, criteria (for example, roles list) and desired output for this data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=CAJKo3KRFk

Comment: The link opens the fiddle clear of data.

Comment: Sorry my bad here is a new link 
 
[link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8PTegYvWFgixoWVGrUDsaS/0)
And I am using mysql 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Got it I was trying to join alias of the table instead of the actual table

```
select json_arrayagg(
               json_object
                   (
                       'id', r1.role_id,
                       'task', (select json_arrayagg(
                                              json_object(
                                                      'id', task.task_id
                                                  ))
                               from task
                                        join role_task rt on task.task_id = rt.task_id
                                        join role on rt.role_id = role.role_id
                                        where role.role_id = r1.role_id
                       )
                   )
           )
from role r1
where r1.role_id = @role_1
   or r1.role_id = @role_4
```

Comment: Both queries (in Q and in A) seems to have excess references.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand what you meant by excess references. The query in answer can be further optimized using common table expression so that we don't have to query for the desired role.

Comment: I mean that you use 2 copies of `role` table whereas one copy must be enough.

Comment: Yeah solved that using cte. here is a link using [cte](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8PTegYvWFgixoWVGrUDsaS/0). Please let me know if it can be further optimized

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           role_id,
           JSON_OBJECT('task',
                       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('uuid', 
                                                 task_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY role_id),
                       'uuid',
                       role_id) single_object
    FROM role
    NATURAL JOIN role_task
    NATURAL JOIN task
    WHERE role_id IN ('role_1', 'role_4')
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(single_object)
INTO @temp
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfccfc3d22607e5014a8e2f2f8737709)

Comment: Can't upvote however thanks for introducing me to window function